# Applying conditions on the Foreign Key using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to apply conditions on foreign key of customer entity i.e Orders, I want to load only the orders whose IsCancelFlag is false.(The result will be of type customer i.e Customer object, and it conatins a set of Order objects) But while iterating through the returned results, I can see all the orders under the customer, irrespective of whether its cancelled or not. Is it possible to apply conditions on foreign key in nhibernate

```
        ICriteria _criteria= session.CreateCriteria<Customer>();
        _criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("CustomerId", 12));
        _criteria.CreateAlias("FKorders","FKorders");
        _criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("FKorders.IsCancelFlag", false));
        return _criteria.UniqueResult<Customer>();
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729599/nhibernate-criteria-for-selecting-a-parent-if-a-child-in-a-collection-ahs-a-spec)   give you what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The above pointed will apply the condition on child and return the parent, Instead I want apply condition on children, and get parent as well children. I can see alternatives using Linq, But I need Nhibernate to do the the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Property names seems weired but maybe you want

```
var query =
    from c in session.Query<Customer>()
    from o in c.Orders
    where o.IsCanceled
    select new { Customer = c, Order = o }

var results = query.AsEnumerable()
    .ToLookup(a => a.Customer, a => a.Order);
```

this will return a `ILookup<Customer, Orders>`. NHibernate won't return a Customer with partially initialised Orders since this will be a broken model and change tracking would be broken.